# Batch file - set variable in “if” then "set"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to have a menu with some names. Each name will be represented with a number.
If I enter the number. It will open youtube or google.

I can do this with the (goto) option but in this case I am trying to replace the word droploc with youtube or google for example. Is it possible?

```
@echo off
@echo menu
@echo enter 1 for google
@echo enter 2 for youtube
    set google=1                           
    set youtube=2                          

    REM Example 1                          

    if "%1%" == "1" (                      
      set dropLoc=1                        
    )                                      

    echo %dropLoc%                         
    start "link" "https://dropLoc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not prompting for a value to process. Try the following, it should get you started.

```
@echo off

:Menu
@echo menu
@echo enter 1 for google
@echo enter 2 for youtube

REM Prompt user to enter a value.
SET /P Selection=Enter selection:

SET dropLoc=null

REM Set the dropLoc based on the user selection.
IF "%Selection%" == "1" SET dropLoc=www.google.com
IF "%Selection%" == "2" SET dropLoc=www.youtube.com

REM If no valid selection, send the user back to the menu.
IF "%dropLoc%" == "null" (
    ECHO Enter a valid selection.
    GOTO Menu
)

echo %dropLoc%                         
start "link" "https://%dropLoc%
```

Comment: I am very new with batch file. I have spent about 20 hours with this. You made it in a moment. Thank you.

Comment: @kboga - Glad to help. We all have to start somewhere. Keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try
Set droploc="google"
Inside your if clause